# Double to int conversion in C

Tags: c, int, type-conversion, double

I have a structure variable health that can be accessed as disk->health, and it is of type double. I am trying to print it as a double and then convert it into an int and print it again.

```
printf("The disk health in loop is: %lf\n", disk_ptr->health);
//result is: 13230000014.560297
printf("The disk health in loop is: %i\n", (int) floor(disk_ptr->health));
//result is: -2147483648
printf("The disk health in loop is: %d\n", (int) floor(disk_ptr->health));
//result is: -2147483648
```

The code above is what I am using. I want the second result to output: 13230000014, but instead it is giving me a strange negative number.

Comment: Did you `#include <math.h>`?

Comment: Yes, I did include it

Comment: I suspect your `int`s are only 32 bits, which can only represent up to 2147483648.

Comment: The number seems too large for an `int` to handle.

Comment: to truncate the value, just `(int)disk_ptr->health` is enough.

Comment: Unless the value is negative, of course, which would indicate a particularly unhealthy disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said that you want it to print `13230000014`, but this value is greater than the maximum value than an int can hold, which is actually `2^31 - 1` (on most systems). You would need to stop using the `%i` specifier and switch to a bigger specifier, like `%lld`, and cast to a `long long` instead.

Like this:

```
printf("The disk health in loop is: %lld\n", (long long) floor(disk_ptr->health));
```

Note that you have to change both the casting as well as the format specifier, or `printf` will still treat the argument as an int.

If you want to be more explicit about using a 64 bit integer, you can consider including `stdint.h`, and making a cast to `int64_t` instead of a `long long`.

EDIT: Note that the floor call is redundant in your case, as casting to `long long` will automatically truncate the decimal. I left it in the above example to better match your code, but just know that it isn't necessary.

Comment: just `(long long)disk_ptr->health` is enough. The `floor` call is redundant

Answer (score 7):

`13230000014` is larger than a 32-bit integer, so you can't store it in an `int` if an `int` is 32 bits. If you have a 64-bit computer, you can try casting to a `long` instead of an `int`. Note that `long` is not guaranteed to be 64 bits.

Edit: According to the comments, the types `int64_t` and `long long` are guaranteed to be 64 bits, so you can use those.

Comment: Don't use long. Long is 64-bit on Linux, but 32-bit on Windows. Use long long, or one of the specific-length types in stdint.h

Comment: @tloach Or better `int64_t` from `stdint.h`. By the way this is why `floor()` returns `float` or `double`, because of integer overflow.

Comment: @Adrian I suggest you to edit your answer to replace `long` with `long long` that is guaranteed to hold 64-bit numbers.

Comment: @Adrian On my computer, `sizeof(long)` returns 4, and `sizeof(long long)` returns 8, which is perfectly valid according to the standards. I would  recommend `long long` or `int64_t`